# How to use extract function in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, raster, shapefile

I am using the extract function in a loop. See below.

```
for (i in 1:length(list_shp_Tanzania)){
  LU_Mod2000<- extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=list_shp_Tanzania[[i]], fun=maj)
}
```

Where maj function is:

```
maj <- function(x){
  y <- as.numeric(names(which.max(table(x))))
  return(y)
}
```

I was expecting to get i outputs, but I get only one output once the loop is done. Somebody knows what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In order not to overwrite your return values of `extract()` over and over again, you may want to create a vector: `LU_Mod2000 <- c(LU_Mod2000, extract(...))`. But probably your `for` loop is not the most efficient solution.

Comment: Could you add the `library()` call for the `extract` function for those that don't know where to find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution in this kind of situation is to create a list and then assign the result of each iteration to the corresponding element of the list:

```
LU_Mod2000 <- vector("list", length(list_shp_Tanzania))
for (i in 1:length(list_shp_Tanzania)){
    LU_Mod2000[[i]] <- extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=list_shp_Tanzania[[i]], fun=maj)    
}
```

Do not do

```
LU_Mod2000 <- c(LU_Mod2000, extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=list_shp_Tanzania[[i]], fun=maj))
```

inside the loop. This will create unnecessary copies and will take long to run. Use the list method, and after the loop, convert the list of results to the desired format (usually using `do.call(LU_Mod2000, <some function>)`)

Alternatively, you could substitute the for loop with `lapply`, which is what many people seem to prefer

```
LU_Mod2000 <- lapply(list_shp_Tanzania, function(z) extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=z, fun=maj))
```

Comment: Nice. And do you know how I can assigne the column names in the lapply function? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you mean because I don't know what `extract()` returns... does it return a data frame whose columns you wish to rename? If yes, this can be done by modifying the function inside `lapply`; i.e. `function(z) { result <- extract(...); colnames(result) <- ...}`

Comment: Well I have 61 objects like this one and I want to give a name to the head of the column.
   '   [,1]
 [1,]   12
 [2,]   12
 [3,]   12
 [4,]   12
 [5,]   12
 [6,]   12
 [7,]   12
 [8,]   12
 [9,]   12
[10,]   11
[11,]   11
[12,]   12
[13,]   11
[14,]   12
[15,]   12'

Comment: Yes, that can be done by setting colnames inside the lapply function

Comment: Indeed but all the row in each objects disapeared. I only have the column head left in each object. Do you know how I can fix it? This is my new line of script: `LU_Mod2000<-lapply(list_shp_Tanzania, function(z) {LU_Mod2000<-extract(x=rc_Mod2000_LC, y=z, fun=maj); colnames(LU_Mod2000[,1]) <-c('LU_2000')})`

Comment: This is happening because the function is returning the last call rather than the whole data frame. You have to tell it to return LU_Mod2000 at the end